# what is the associated slave terminal for emulator master terminal?

Tags: terminal, devices, tty, block-device

for master `/dev/pts/x` maps to slave terminal `/dev/tty[S]y`, what/where is the mapping function/database from `x` to `[S]y`?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel acts as the mapping function/database.  Each of those slave devices is a connection (identified by the device major/minor number) and stored in the kernel.

Comment: question is about what is the associated tty[x]y(slave) to pts[a]b(master)?